# Gridview datasource from database stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

This is the database stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getShift]
    @rfiddata VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        pd.TP, s.s_name, dt.dt_type, dr.dr_date
    FROM 
        TA_System_PersonalDetails pd
    INNER JOIN 
        TA_System_DutyRequest dr ON pd.TP = DR.TP
    INNER JOIN 
        TA_System_Duty d ON dr.d_ID = d.d_ID
    INNER JOIN 
        TA_System_Shift s ON d.s_ID = s.s_ID
    INNER JOIN 
        TA_System_DutyType dt ON d.dt_ID = dt.dt_ID
    WHERE 
        pd.rfid_card = @rfiddata
        AND dr.dr_date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
END
```

And this the C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.getShift", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfiddata", data);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

gvDetails.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

The gridview still not able to show the value. And this project is in windows form C#. Hence, there is no `DataBind()` function. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You need to fill a `DataTable` and set it as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help

First we create a connector to connect to the database

```
string cnStr = @"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=usr;password=pwe; Initial Catalog=theDataBase;Data Source=yourDatasource";
```

and create a `SqlCommand` and after set the `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

Then create a `SqlConnection` and Open Database:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnStr))
{

   con.Open();

   cmd.Connection = con;
   cmd.CommandText = "dbo.getShift";    // this is the stored procedure to       execute
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

 }//Connection automatically closes here without the need to call conn.Close()
```

Then create a dataset to be filled as the datasource for the gridview:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);

grdYourGrid.DataSource = ds;
grdYourGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: Better yet - create a `DataTable` since you're only expecting to get back one set of data